# C++ boost::shared_ptr operator[] details

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Boost documentation says

> Starting with Boost release 1.53, shared_ptr can be used to hold a
>   pointer to a dynamically allocated array.

I have an simple class and using `boost::shared_ptr` to hold array of `std::deque` within it:

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::deque<uint32_t> []> someArray;
```

I would like to have a method to return specified deque from array for read only:

```
std::deque<uint32_t> MyClass::myMethod(boost::uint32_t arrayIndex) const{            
        return someArray[arrayIndex];
}
```

Doesn't this approach violate object's constancy?

Comment: std::deque<uint32_t> is not an array

Comment: This `boost::shared_ptr<std::deque<uint32_t> >` is just a shared pointer to a deque, it is not a shared pointer to an array of deques.

Comment: Sorry, sure, it was a literal error. I meant same construction. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Doesn't this approach violate object's constancy?

No. Yes. Maybe. 
It obviously does not affect *syntactic* constancy, since the compiler does not complain. This is because syntactic constancy requires the object and its members, in this case especially the smart pointer, to be const. It does *not* require the pointee (i.e. the array of deques) to be const.
The *semantic* constancy is another thing. If the array belongs to your object, changing the array means changing the object, and having the object const means not changing the array. It's up to you to enforce semantic constness that is not syntactic constness. However, in such a case I would not use a `shared_ptr` but a `std::vector`, because that's expressing single ownership, while `shared_ptr` is shared ownership - obviously. In addition, `std::vector` is designed to enforce semantic constancy, meaning the library implementors enforced the contained elements to be const in a const vector.
However, since I don't know the context of your class and the deque array, and since you use `shared_ptr` wich explicitly means shared ownership, *maybe* you need semantic constness, maybe not.

**But** since you said you want a read-only access and you return by value, that access won't change the array contents, sou you might be well. Returning by const reference might do what you need too, plus it avoids unnecessary temporary copies wich might be quite expensive depending on how many objects the dequeues store

Comment: Sorry, I should never more asking a question writing a code from my mind. Of course I meant [] and std::deque as method return type. I bring my apologises. I will edit my question.

Comment: @vard Ok, I removed that parts from my answer, I hope I left what answered your question.